# How do I change/move my dining table/bed?

Tags: story-of-seasons

WHen I try and re-arrange my house. I cannot move my bed or dining table. I can understand not having a bed... but why can't I at least move my dining table?

Can I swap these items out at least with ones that I prefer the look of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems you can't move around these objects, but you can swap them out if you have a matching "type" in your inventory by going into "edit home" mode then selecting the object you want to change.